# Pass extra parameters to Django Model Forms along with request.POST

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a Rating models with some fields in which ip and url and required fields.
I get some of these fields in request.POST but I have to pass ip and url to the modelform from my view.
My Model:

```
class Rating(models.Model):

    rating = core_fields.SmallIntegerRangeField(min_value=1, max_value=5)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=2048)
    tracker = models.ForeignKey("core.Tracker", db_index=True)
    ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(db_index=True)
    user_agent = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_index=True)
   _content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, db_index=True)
   special_object = GenericForeignKey('_content_type', 'object_id')

class Meta:
    unique_together = ['_content_type', 'tracker', 'object_id']
    verbose_name = ('rating')
```

In my views.py :

```
form = RatingModelForm(request.POST, ip=ip, url=url)

if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save(commit=False)
    instance.save()
```

And my in forms.py:

```
class RatingModelForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Rating
        exclude = ('special_object',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ip = kwargs.pop('ip', None)
        url = kwargs.pop('url', None)

        super(RatingModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['ip'].initial = ip
        self.fields['url'].initial = url
```

I have tried setting initial values but the form.is_valid() give False and and states that ip and url are required. How do proceed with this ?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of a ModelForm is data. Ie the expected data for the form. As you mentioned that `request.POST` is an immutable querydict. Make a new dictionary by making a [copy out of it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict), modify that and then pass it into the form.

If you use dict() on a django QueryDict it will look odd. So you have to make a copy of the query dict to make it work properly.

```
data = request.POST.copy()
data['ip'] = ip
data['url'] = url
form = RatingModelForm(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but request.POST is an immutable querydict in my case. Can't modify that

Comment: @roushankumar I modified my answer.

Comment: @roushankumar Did that help?

Comment: Yes it did.. Thanks for the answer. Also it would be great if you can help me with how to proceed in case i want to pass extra parameters to the form along with request.post. Do we have to override any of form methods for that ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to override any form methods. In the view where you get `request.POST` you can store ip and url in a dictionary like the above. Then pass the dictionary into the form. 

When you validate the form it should be valid, right? Or do you have another problem?

Comment: Well if I proceed this way I am getting field validation errors which were not coming earlier.

Comment: I also have a foreign key field and a Integer field in my model. Now i get the errors that  : 'Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.'  and 'Enter a whole number for the foreign key field and the integer field respectively. These errors were not coming when I was passing request.post to the model form

Comment: Both the IntegerField and ForeignKey field are mandatory when saving the model, right? Provide the data for the foreign key and the integerfield in the same way you provided url and ip and it should work out.

Comment: Since I am copying from request.POST, these data are already present in the data dictionary. Still i am getting this error.

Comment: Can you print `request.POST` so I can see what it actually contains?

Comment: <QueryDict: {u'_content_type': [u'245'], u'rating': [u'5'], u'object_id': [u'1489'], u'tracker': [u'53064351L'], u'user_agent': [u'PC'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'RCLxX1Wp8YZY6Ii61mgV2eUNQIQPow1hzi11VOTmyUDIki4swUkHUIfnkT5y7WBd']}>

Comment: can you also update your question with the entire model?

Comment: Updated the question with my model

Comment: @roushan It looks like it's containing everything that it should contain. Can you please try to make a copy of the query dict instead. Ie `request.POST.copy()` and then update the contents.